# Handle exceptions within the SPOOL command statements in sql*plus

Tags: sqlplus

I have a sql file with a pool statement in which a series of sql statements are executed.
I would like to know if it is possible to control the exceptions that occur in the sql statements within the spool command.

This is a example of code:

```
 WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
SET ECHO OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

SET VERIFY OFF
SET feedback off
SET pagesize 0
SET TIMING OFF
SET TIME OFF

SPOOL myscript.sql
  
@@myscript2.sql
SPOOL off

SET TIMING ON
SET TIME ON
SET feedback on
SET VERIFY ON
PROMPT Ejecutando Scripts
@myscript.sql

PROMPT Fin de ejecucion
EXIT
```

Thanks